# Shuffling numpy array without commas

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array.

```
[['5.1' '3.5' '1.4' '0.2' 'Iris-setosa']
 ['4.9' '3.0' '1.4' '0.2' 'Iris-setosa']
 ['5.6' '3.0' '4.5' '1.5' 'Iris-versicolor']
 ['5.8' '2.7' '4.1' '1.0' 'Iris-versicolor']
 ['6.2' '3.4' '5.4' '2.3' 'Iris-virginica']
 ['5.9' '3.0' '5.1' '1.8' 'Iris-virginica']]
```

How do I shuffle the rows ?

I tried `numpy.random.shuffle()` but it was returning `None` probably due to absence of commas

Comment: There are no commas displayed because this is the output of `print array_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.random.shuffle`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) is designed to work *in-place* meaning that it should return `None` and instead modify your array.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
print(x)
# [[0 1 2]
#  [3 4 5]
#  [6 7 8]]

np.random.shuffle(x)
print(x)
# [[3 4 5]
#  [0 1 2]
#  [6 7 8]]
```